# Tumblr to Feedburner to iTunes only 15 episodes showing

Tags: rss, itunes, tumblr, feedburner

I am using a tumbler site (http://howmuchcanyouchugfoo.tumblr.com/tagged/podcast/rss) to populate a podcast on itunes, by way of feedburner. Despite enabling infinite scroll, Tumblr seems to only make the last 15 episodes available. I have tried adding ?num=40 to the url, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use either [Feedcombine](http://www.feedcombine.com/), Chimp Feedr, or Yahoo Pipes to merge the feeds into one single xml link as I learned here:

http://www.creativeramblings.com/3-tools-to-combine-multiple-feeds-into-one/

I tried all three sites and settled on Feedcombine as Chimp Feedr didn't seem to work on Feedburner, and Yahoo Pipes was displaying the posts in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik Tumblr only generates an RSS feed, per page not per site:

```
http://howmuchcanyouchugfoo.tumblr.com/tagged/podcast/page/2/rss
http://howmuchcanyouchugfoo.tumblr.com/tagged/podcast/page/3/rss
http://howmuchcanyouchugfoo.tumblr.com/tagged/podcast/page/4/rss
...
```

So you will need to manual grab / scrape these. Infinite scroll doesn't update or create a new RSS link for each page that is loaded sadly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! How would one go about manually grabbing or combining these pages?

Comment: @user2979360 Sadly I have no idea.